# Разбор строки c телефонами на Javascript||PHP

Tags: php, javascript, строки

Есть строка вида `+7 (495) 605-63-80 +7 (903) 270-70-00 +7 (495) 605-67-88`
Как из этой строк средствами Javascript||PHP получить массив из трех телефонов?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$tel = "+7 (495) 605-63-80 +7 (903) 270-70-00 +7 (495) 605-67-88";
$telArr = explode("+7", $tel);

print_r($telArr);
```

Как то так))
Просто текст для того что бы набрать 30 символов )))

Answer (score 1):

На скорую руку...

`var stringPhone = "+7 (495) 605-63-80 +7 (903) 270-70-00 +7 (495) 605-67-88";
var result = stringPhone.split('+7');
for(var i=0;i<result.length;i++){result[i]="+7"+result[i];}
alert(result);`

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ozs2g1og/)

Answer (score 1):

Или  например вот так - https://regex101.com/r/PCtj3D/1. Естественно, если номер в строке будет содержать другое количество пробелом между собою - не найдет ничего.

```js
const regex = /\+7.{16}/g;
const str = `+7 (495) 605-63-80 +7 (903) 270-70-00 +7 (495) 605-67-88`;
console.log(str.match(regex));
```